# Scable qty going to nagative value

Tags: magento2, product, database, catalog, qty

In Magento2 Scalable qty going to nagative value.

Is there anyone have idea which cases Scalable Qty going to nagative value?

Answer (score 0):

Negative scalable quantity in Magento 2 can occur due to **inventory mismanagement, concurrent orders, custom code or extensions, database inconsistencies, or configuration issues.**

Answer (score 0):

**Here are a few possibilities:**

- Incorrect configuration: If there are misconfigurations or incorrect
  settings in your Magento 2 store's inventory management, it could
  potentially result in negative scalable quantities. For example, if
  the system is not properly tracking inventory adjustments or if there
  are conflicts with the inventory management settings, it may lead to
  negative values.
- Manual adjustments: If someone manually adjusts the scalable quantity
  of a product and enters a negative value by mistake, it can cause the
  quantity to become negative. This could happen when making inventory
  adjustments directly in the Magento admin panel or through API calls.
- Customizations or extensions: If you have customizations or
  third-party extensions installed in your Magento 2 store that
  interact with the inventory management system, they could introduce
  bugs or errors that cause negative scalable quantities.

**To troubleshoot the issue and prevent negative scalable quantities, consider the following steps:**

- Review your inventory management configuration and ensure that all
  settings are properly configured.
- Check for any customizations or extensions that might be interfering
  with the inventory management functionality. Disable or temporarily
  remove them to see if the issue persists.
- Monitor any manual inventory adjustments made and ensure that
  negative values are not entered accidentally.
- Stay up-to-date with Magento 2 updates and patches, as they often
  include bug fixes and improvements related to inventory management.